# Free RTMP audio player

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, rtmp

Does anyone know any free RTMP audio player? I could find several video players, but not for audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there have some audio player, you can try it!

Free RTMP Streaming Player 2.0

http://www.topshareware.com/Free-RTMP-Streaming-Player-download-57014.htm